# How do I keep a user logged into a WebView app?

Tags: java, android, progressive-web-apps

I have a problem: the WebView is not keeping the user logged when it closes and opens the app again. So the user needs login each time.

I search different solutions but none worked. I know it should be working because `appsgeyser` and other websites offer this functionality in their apk for PWA.

My `mainactivity`, Also I used the cookie manager, and more but not works.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Set your theme before super.onCreate() to replace your previous theme of Manifest
    setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //TODO: add your MainActivity code here
    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    //webSettings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);


    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){});
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){});

    webView.loadUrl("https://www.myapp.app");

}
```

Comment: I think you need to save the cookie to shared preferences, and load it every time app launches.

Comment: Hello Marcelo. If you have the ability to choose, use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of WebView as it uses shared cookie storage (among different Chrome instances) so you can achieve single sign on experience that you're looking for.